# Laravel 7 with Laradock on production: email verification 403 invalid signature

Tags: laravel, nginx-location, laradock

There are many posts out there and StackOverflow answers, but none has helped me solve this problem.

I am using Laradock for a Laravel app on a production server. The Laravel version is 7.24.0 on Nginx and PHP 7.4.

However, if I test the email verification via mailtrap, I get this error

> 403 | Invalid signature.

I already have executed `php artisan key:generate` and I can see it in my .env file:

```
APP_NAME="The cool app"
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:S1ABrOXZ1ldmYqfjBvZfupwBNM+m10MWINqEvj/eGbg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://my-domain.com
```

Originally, the Nginx default configuration is:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # For https
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    #    root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
    #    log_not_found off;
    #}
}
```

I have tried that one as well:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56738758/1883256).

But nothing works, except in my local environment.

A sample of the URL is.

```
https://my-domain.com/email/verify/3/28d707536a36800a7cfaaaa5f5e29eca3ac2b38a?expires=1597101566&signature=2685421462a1756e38bee693801f11e2f2ed6645e3d0ad361413a758b9ca6fab
```

I checked both the "verify" email button and the web browser URLs and they look the same.

Additionally, I have just tried

```
$ php artisan config:cache
```

But no luck :/ I still get that `403 | Invalid signature` error

Can anyone shed some light on this? Otherwise, how to debug this?

---

**Solved! Hurra**
I have applied what is said in this [GitHub issue answered by yawmanford](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28311#issuecomment-510775224):

Inside **`AppServiceProvider.php`**

```
public function boot()
{
    if($this->app->environment('production'))
    {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Then in **`TrustProxies.php`**

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Finally, inside the `workspace` container I ran:

`artisan config:cache`

And that did the trick!

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

For me, `php artisan config:cache` on the production server did the trick.

Within the `hasCorrectSignature` method in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/routing/UrlGenerator.php`, print out the `call_user_func($this->keyResolver)`.

If it's not the same as the APP_KEY in your environment variables, then you'll need to flush the cache (`php artisan config:cache`).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason for this is your nginx configuration. Can you try this instead?

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

I also see that you are using `https` in the app but your nginx configs don't have `SSL` configs. Can you try and use `http` in the app see how it performs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it and it didn't work. But I have just found out how to make it work [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28311#issuecomment-510775224). Moreover, I applied `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer. Is it the correct answer? if not please share your solution. It will probab;y help future readers.